# Emacs -- sort list of directories / files by modification date

Tags: emacs, elisp

The function `(directory-files-and-attributes "~/" 'full nil t)` creates an *unsorted* list of files and directories for the home directory.  The result appears to be in a format similar to `file-attributes`, the documentation for which can be viewed at the following link:  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Attributes.html

The goal of this thread is to create a list that is sorted by modification date / time -- with the newest at the beginning of the list, and oldest at the ending of the list.

Lastly, I would like to turn that detailed list into a simple list of just absolute paths of the files / directories -- maintaining the same order that was achieved in the above-described sort.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`directory-files-and-attributes` returns a list.  Thankfully, there's a lot of Lisp functions to transform lists.

First, you want to get the list sorted by comparing the 6th elements of each entry.  You can do that using the native Emacs Lisp `sort` function, which takes a comparison function as second element:

```
(sort (directory-files-and-attributes "~")
      #'(lambda (x y) (time-less-p (nth 6 x) (nth 6 y))))
```

The same can be achieved perhaps more clearly using the Common Lisp sort function:

```
(cl-sort (directory-files-and-attributes "~")
         #'time-less-p
         :key #'(lambda (x) (nth 6 x)))
```

Now you want to extract just the first element of each entry — use `mapcar` to apply a function to all elements of the list:

```
(mapcar #'car
        (sort (directory-files-and-attributes "~")
              #'(lambda (x y) (time-less-p (nth 6 x) (nth 6 y)))))
```